# Get nth level on self-referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a self-referencing table which has at max 5 levels

```
groupid   | parentid  | detail
--------- | --------- | ---------
Group A   | Highest   | nope 
Group B   | Group A   | i need this  
Highest   | NULL      | nope 
Group C   | Group B   | nope 
Group D   | Group C   | nope
```

I have a transaction table which lookups to the groupid on the table above to retrieve the detail value where groupid = Group B. The values of the groupid on the transaction table is only between Group B to D and will never go any higher.

```
txnid     | groupid   | desired   | desired
--------- | --------- | --------- | ---------
1         | Group D   | Group B   | i need this
2         | Group B   | Group B   | i need this
3         | Group C   | Group B   | i need this
4         | Group B   | Group B   | i need this
```

How should my T-SQL script be like to attain the desired column? I can left join to the self referencing table multiple times to get until group B it's not consistent on how many time I need to join back.

Greatly appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: Why are stopping at `Group A` and what is the purpose of the `desired` column?

Comment: do you know the level of each groupid on your transactions table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's a hierarchy of the levels in the company. Example would be: Highest - Company, Group A - Sector, Group B - Department, Group C - Team, Group D - Individual. Apologies if its confusing as I have to mask actual representations. In my example the desired column should take the value of the department. I need to store it in the transacations so I could apply subsetting/row-level permissions later on in the transactions table

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.  As no one else has answered, I may be correct that your question is not clear.

Comment: @McNets in the example above the transactions table has 3 levels (B,C,D) at max. They don't put values higher than Group B

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to stop at Group B, not Group A because that contains the value of the Department. I need to store the department on the desired column as I'll be using it for filtering the transaction table later on

Comment: If you always want to stop at Group B then what is the point of a hierarchical query?

Comment: I know there are 5 levels, I repeat the question: do you know the level number on your transactions table 1=a, 2=b, 3=c, 4=d, 5=e?

Answer (score 1):

Still not clear to me how do you know which is the GROUP B, I suppose it's the record where the parent of it parent is null.

> ```
> create table org(groupid char(1), parentid char(1), details varchar(20));
> insert into org values
> ('a', null, 'nope'),('b', 'a', 'I need this'),('c', 'b', 'nope'),('d', 'c', 'nope'),('e', 'd', 'nope');
>
> create table trans(id int, groupid char(1));
> insert into trans values
> (1, 'b'),(2, 'c'),(3, 'c'),(4, 'd'),(5, 'e');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> with all_levels as
> (
>     select     ob.groupid groupid_b, oc.groupid groupid_c, 
>                od.groupid groupid_d, oe.groupid groupid_e, 
>                ob.details
>     from       org ob
>     inner join org oc
>     on         oc.parentid = ob.groupid
>     inner join org od
>     on         od.parentid = oc.groupid
>     inner join org oe
>     on         oe.parentid = od.groupid
>     where      ob.parentid is not null
> ) select * from all_levels;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> groupid_b | groupid_c | groupid_d | groupid_e | details    
> :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :----------
> b         | c         | d         | e         | I need this
> ```

> ```
> --= build a 4 levels row
> with all_levels as
> (
>     select     ob.groupid groupid_b, oc.groupid groupid_c, 
>                od.groupid groupid_d, oe.groupid groupid_e, 
>                ob.details
>     from       org ob
>     inner join org oc
>     on         oc.parentid = ob.groupid
>     inner join org od
>     on         od.parentid = oc.groupid
>     inner join org oe
>     on         oe.parentid = od.groupid
>     where      ob.parentid is not null
> ) 
>     --= no matter what groupid returns b group details
>     , only_b as
>     (
>         select groupid_b as groupid, groupid_b, details from all_levels
>         union all
>         select groupid_c as groupid, groupid_b, details from all_levels
>         union all
>         select groupid_d as groupid, groupid_b, details from all_levels
>         union all
>         select groupid_e as groupid, groupid_b, details from all_levels
>     )
>     --= join with transactions table
>     select     id, t.groupid, groupid_b, ob.details
>     from       trans t
>     inner join only_b ob
>     on         ob.groupid = t.groupid;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | groupid | groupid_b | details    
> -: | :------ | :-------- | :----------
>  1 | b       | b         | I need this
>  2 | c       | b         | I need this
>  3 | c       | b         | I need this
>  4 | d       | b         | I need this
>  5 | e       | b         | I need this
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ece0b05f07859a74208f3dc3e0c05b12)*

You can deal with a recursive function too, but I don't believe it can be better on terms of performance.

> ```
> create function findDetails(@groupid char(1))
> returns varchar(100)
> as
> begin
>     declare @parentid char(1) = '1';
>     declare @next_parentid char(1) = '1';
>     declare @details varchar(100) = '';
>
>     while @next_parentid is not null
>     begin
>         select     @details = org.details, @parentid = org.parentid, @next_parentid = op.parentid
>         from       org
>         inner join org op
>         on         op.groupid = org.parentid
>         where      org.groupid = @groupid
>
>         set @groupid = @parentid;
>     end
>
>     return @details;
> end
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select id, groupid, dbo.findDetails(groupid) as details_b
> from   trans;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | groupid | details_b  
> -: | :------ | :----------
>  1 | b       | I need this
>  2 | c       | I need this
>  3 | c       | I need this
>  4 | d       | I need this
>  5 | e       | I need this
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0c3434c7eb7207b4a34bf8a6b2ba9aab)*